# get Contenteditable div html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jsfiddle at [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2tr3wnaw/1/).

I have a contenteditable div. I want the html of whatever I write in that `div`, on the click of anchor tag.

Right now, `div` is working but nothing is showing on click of the anchor tag.

```
function getcode()
{
    var content = $('#my-contenteditable-div').html();
    alert (content);
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4kpjdhw0/ use "No wrap - in head" option from left side options

Comment: plz could you explain what is No wrap @Satpal

Comment: "do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in <head> section" Read [Docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html) apart from that no issue with your code it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as well:

```
$("a").click(function () {
    alert($('#my-contenteditable-div').html());
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tr3wnaw/4/)

Then you don't need to write separate functions and attach it to the `onclick` event attribute of the `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
// get the link
var link = document.getElementById("linkId");
// add click listener to it
link.addEventListener("click",getcode,false);
// you handler
function getcode()
{
    var content = document.getElementById("my-contenteditable-div");
    alert (content.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you can go with jquery

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yohcqum5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#gethtml').on('click', function(e) {    
    var content = $('#my-contenteditable-div').html();
    alert (content);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can use this use id in `a` and a div to show data

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="my-contenteditable-div">
  sdfsdfds
</div>
<a href="#" id="getcode" >Get HTML</a>
<div id="show"></div>
```

and jQuery

```
$( "#getcode" ).click(function() {
  var contents = $('#my-contenteditable-div').html();
  $("#show").text(contents);
});
```